# Determining the Big O complexity for "for" loops.

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I have 3 for problems I having trouble determing the Big O complexity for.

A.

```
int x = 0;
for ( int y = 1; y <= n * n; y++)
   for ( int z = 1; z < y; z++ )
      x++;
```

I want to say n<sup>3</sup> because the first loop is n<sup>2</sup> and the inside is n.

B.

```
int x = 0;
for ( int y = 1; y <= n; y++)
   for ( int z = i; z <= n; z += 3)
      x++;
```

I want to say Big O(n) since the outside loop is N and the inside I believe is Big O(3).

C.

```
for ( int x = 1; x <= n; x++)
    for ( int y = n; y > 0; y /= 2)
```

This one has been confusing me. I think the inside loop is Logn since you divide by 2 everytime it is run. The outside looks to just b n, so would this be Big O (nlogn) or just Big O(logn)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the first one, A:**

You need to se how many iterations the inner loop makes *in total*. So how many iterations does the inner loop have? It will have first 1, then 2, then 3 all the way until N^2.
So we get:

[image: Big-O notation formula A]

**For the next one, B:**

Again, we look at how many iteration the *inner* loop does:

It runs the same number of iterations each time, n times that is. And every time it iterates one third of n. So we get:

[image: Big-O notation formula B]

**For the last one, C**

Again, the inner loop counts:

It iterates [image: log2n] on its own. But it does it n times. So we get:

[image: Big-O notation formula C]

I hope this helps, and let me know if something is unclear:

For further and understanding on the topic, I recommend [this site](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html).

Comment: Ah ok this helps and I appreciate the link. I think seeing it written out is what cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

### In regards to A it is O(n^3), which is a lower bound than O(n^4)

```
int x = 0;
for ( int y = 1; y <= n * n; y++)
   for ( int z = 1; z < y; z++ )
      x++;
```

Loop for z. z is going only to the current value of y

```
y=1
z: no loop

y=2
z: 1

y=3
z: 1 2

y=4
z: 1 2 3

...

y=15
z: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

So the inner loop has y-1 steps for each step of n from 1 to 25 (=n^2).

So, I would say it is `T(N) = N^2 * (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + (N-1))`, which is O(n^3), which is an even lower bound than the mentioned O(n^4) in the other answer.

### The other answers fro B and C are correct as of reading this thread.